# Theorem 6.14 from Gilbarg/Trudinger "Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second order"

Tags: partial-differential-equations

A question about the proof of Theorem 6.14 (p.107) from Gilbarg-Trudinger "Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second order" .  This theorem satates that the Dirichlet problem
\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
  \begin{cases}
  Lu=f, \ \ \Omega\\
  u=\varphi.\ \ \partial \Omega,
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
has a unique $C^{2,\alpha}(\bar{\Omega})$ solution, where $L$ is srictly elliptic with $c\leq 0$, $f$ and the coefficients of $L$ belong to $C^{\alpha}(\bar{\Omega})$, $\Omega$ is a $C^{2,\alpha}$  domain and  $\varphi\in C^{2,\alpha}(\bar{\Omega})$.

In the proof, I don't know how to find a mapping $y=\psi(x)$ satisfying the following condtions:

(1) $\widetilde{N}=\psi(N)$, where $N$ is a neighborhood of $x_0\in \partial \Omega$;

(2) $\psi(N\cap \bar{\Omega})$ contains a ball $B$ and a boundary portion $T$ of $N\cap \partial \Omega$ containing $x_0$ is mapped by $\psi$ into a boundary portion $\widetilde{T}$ of $B$;

(3) $\psi\in C^{2,\alpha}(N)$ and $\psi^{-1}\in C^{2,\alpha}(\widetilde{N})$.

**The definnition of a $C^{2,\alpha}$ domain:**
A bounded domain $\Omega$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and its boundary are of $C^{2,\alpha}$ $(0\leq \alpha\leq 1)$, if at each point $x_0\in \partial \Omega$ there is a ball $B=B(x_0)$ and a one-to-one mapping $\psi$ of $B$ onto $D\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that :

(1) $\psi(B\cap \Omega)\subset \mathbb{R}_{+}^n$,

(2) $\psi(B\cap \partial \Omega) \subset \partial \mathbb{R}_{+}^n$,

(3) $\psi\in C^{2,\alpha}(B)$, $\psi^{-1}\in C^{2,\alpha}(D)$,

where $\mathbb{R}_{+}^n=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: x_n>0\}$.

We say that the diffeomorphism $\psi$ straightens the boundary near $x_0$.

Any hint would be appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: What is the definition of a $C^{2,\alpha}$ domain?

Comment: A definition comes from Gilbarg-Trudinger "Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second order" (p.94).

Comment: I add the  definition of a $C^{2,\alpha}$ domain at the above.